# Gutenberg extending the existing class

Tags: block-editor

I am building a [prism](https://prismjs.com/) plugin to highlight the code syntaxes. In existing code block there is already a sidebar option with Additional Class Name but i have to manually enter the class name for the syntaxes. Like for `php` syntaxes i have to add `language-php` and so on. To prevent this issue a added a additional sidebar option for code block only that is a drop down with all the supported languages class names.

But now the issue is when i am trying to extend the existing classname i got the validation error.

```
export function addSaveProps( extraProps, blockType, attributes ) {

    // If the current block is valid, add our prop.
    if ( isValidBlockType( blockType.name ) ) {

        if( "undefined" != typeof attributes.prismClass && 
            attributes.prismClass.length ) {

            //extraProps.prismClass = attributes.prismClass;
            extraProps.className = attributes.className+" "+attributes.prismClass;
        }
    }

    return extraProps;
}
```

But with the above code I got the following error:

> blocks.min.js?ver=6.0.4:2 Block validation: Block validation failed for `core/code`

[image]

Is there any way to extend the existing class?

Comment: I checked your code with a custom class and it works (being called as the callback of `blocks.getSaveContent.extraProps`, is this the filter you are using?). For highlighting I think there is a package, already in gutenberg, in case you are interested: [annotations](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/block-api/block-annotations/) but I haven't tested it so Im not sure about it.

Comment: @Alvaro yes i am using the ```blocks.getSaveContent.extraProps``` filter and added the screenshot to the question too. I haven't seen any package to highlighting the syntax in gutenberg.